# Long word in title overflows into right column in suggested edits queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, title

In the suggested edit review queue, it seems if the title of a question contains a very long word it will overflow into the right column. This is the [review item in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28787444).

[image]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 87.0 (64-bit), 1920x1080.

Comment: Repro'ed on Chrome on Windows, too.

Comment: Looks fine at UHD... but not smaller screen sizes.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek does UHD matter? [Screenshot from my 3440px width monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69xcq.png).

Comment: well - If the dev is using a wide enough screen they might not see - least in theory. I almost didn't throw it a review tag cause works for me (tm)

Comment: No repro on win 10 same Firefox, but 1366*768. Ancient laptops rule.

Comment: I want to point out that I can't repro now (even though I did before) unless I shrink my browser's window size. This is probably due to the fact that the review item is completed and the "Actions" div removed.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Side-by-side question review with long title can display overlapping title text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407432/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! I just added word break in the suggested edit review area. Now long words that overflow the column container will break into the next line.

Answer (score 3):

Repro for me on Chrome (version 103.0.5060.71) for Android, resolution 2220×1080 on mobile.

[image]

Can this please be fixed soon? It heavily affects readability and more so often for mobile users.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). You can also [add a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/83747)

Comment: @Rob This is only adding more information to it, and I don't think this should be a new question right? Or does mobile vs computer lead to diff questions?

Comment: This was in the review queue, this was one choice the other that this answer should be a comment.

Comment: @Rob So i dont post this as a new question correct?

Comment: While answers that don't say much more than "reproduced on [device X]" are generally not considered quality answers here, I'm going to err on the side that this should stay. The question only contains a reproduction of the problem on a desktop browser, whereas this issue is more likely to be seen on mobile devices due to the shorter width and that's definitely an argument that this issue should receive higher priority, which is an acceptable use of an [answer to a bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325665/377214).